# I can't create thread on PHPBB3 forum

Tags: c#, phpbb3

My problem is that I get 0 bytes response from server (I'm using Fiddler2 to check this out).

Picture:
[image: wtf]

What I'm doing:

1. Log in. I get cookies.
2. Creating thread

---

```
public void CreateTopic(string subject, string message, string forumId)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        string source = string.Empty;
        string lastClick= string.Empty;
        string creationTime= string.Empty;
        string formToken = string.Empty;

        // GET
        while(true)
        {
            webRequest =
                (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(Url + "posting.php?mode=post&f=" + forumId + "&sid=" + sid);
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Host = Url.Replace("http://", "").Replace("/", "");
            webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
                UpdateSid(Url + "posting.php?mode=post&f=" + forumId + "&sid=" + sid);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        source = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();

        response.Close();

        // Get stuff
        // last click
        Match lastClickMatch = Regex.Match(source, "name=\"lastclick\" value=\"([0-9]{10})\" />");
        if (lastClickMatch.Success) lastClick = lastClickMatch.Groups[1].Value;

        // creation time
        Match creationTimeMatch = Regex.Match(source, "name=\"creation_time\" value=\"([0-9]{10})\" />");
        if (creationTimeMatch.Success) creationTime = creationTimeMatch.Groups[1].Value;

        // form token
        Match formTokenMatch = Regex.Match(source, "name=\"form_token\" value=\"(.{40})\" />");
        if (formTokenMatch.Success) formToken = formTokenMatch.Groups[1].Value;

        // POST
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url + "posting.php?mode=post&f=" + forumId + "&sid=" + sid);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Host = Url.Replace("http://", "").Replace("/", "");
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        string data = "icon=&subject=" + Encode(subject) + "&addbbcode20=100&message=" + Encode(message) + "&attach_sig=on&post=Submit&lastclick=" + lastClick + "&creation_time=" + creationTime + "&form_token=" + formToken;

        byte[] byte1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
        stream.Close();

        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        UpdateSid(Url + "posting.php?mode=post&f=" + forumId + "&sid=" + sid);

        response.Close();
    }
```

I get this on fiddler:
RAW:

```
POST http://stuff.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=8&sid=6d278be1e705fe0261f253bbc96ab7a4
HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Host: stuff.com 
Cookie: phpbb3_goeyz_u=55443;phpbb3_goeyz_k=;phpbb3_goeyz_sid=6d278be1e705fe0261f253bbc96ab7a4 
Content-Length: 165

icon=&subject=g&addbbcode20=100&message=d&attach_sig=on&post=Submit&lastclick=1323904393&creation_time=1323904393&form_token=b81c23e308f0bd3a0a73907efcc8c18e5dba0f7f
```

Response RAW:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 23:13:14 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 
Location: http://stuff.com/games.html 
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html
```

I have no idea what is going on. If you will help me I will be grateful. I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler when you attempt to create the thread from the phpbb3 website?

Comment: You don't get 0 bytes of response, your response body has a length of 0, which is identified by the Content-Length header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why it didn't create thread. It checks:

```
if ($user->data['is_bot'])
```

If you don't want to be a bot, then you have to WAIT for like 8 seconds before sending POST:

```
Thread.Sleep(8100);
```

It resolved all problems for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found this snippet in the source of phpBB 3.0.9:

```
203  // Check permissions
204  if ($user->data['is_bot'])
205  {
206      redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx"));
207  }
```

So they might be pulling you a trick here. Are you sure you are allowed to do what you're trying to?

Anyhow, I think you might to want to change your [user agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7";
```

This might help not being identified as a bot, which perhaps takes place because the default `UserAgent` value is `null`.

Comment: @carck3r then perhaps you should try installing (about) the same version of phpBB3 locally, and verifying that you get the same results. Then you can start debugging phpBB3 (which merely implies tactically placing some `echo`'s here and there in posting.php) to see where things go wrong.

Comment: Yes, I will test it on my server. If you have another ideas then write it. Now I'm going to sleep.

Comment: I still have no idea how to do this. I'm using webClient and it's doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Its returning a status code of 302 Found, which means the server is attempting to redirect you to another page (in your example, "http://stuff.com/games.html").

Comment: Assuming the urls in your example aren't the actual ones, then following the redirect might give you more information on why it doesn't work. It could also require POST instead of GET, perhaps.