# Create topic using a bot

Tags: mechanize, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm in a situation in which i need to be able to create a topics using self created bot. My forum has a special category and user, which can create a topics in that category.

Technology i'm using to create that bot is ruby + mechanize gem but it's not important right now. That bot works in a following way:

1. Sign in as previously mentioned user:

   - visit - `/ucp.php?mode=login`
   - fill the sign-in form using user credentials
   - if, after submiting a form, there is a sign-out link somewhere on the page, threat this whole process as "successfull"
2. Create a topic

   - visit - `/posting.php?mode=post&f=21`
   - fill `subject` field with desired subject
   - fill `message` field with desired message
   - submit a form using `Submit` button

And now, while first point works just great, the second one behaves in a strange way. After submiting a form, there is no error message or anything like that, i'm just getting redirected to `/viewforum.php?f=21` (log's says that it's `302 Moved Temporarily` status) page and the topic is not there.

Can anyone tell me what such behaviour means? Is there any security mechanism i don't know about? Please also note that the new topic form has `form_token` and `creation_time` fields filled correctly while form is beeing submited.

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713867/552936, user is treated as a bot if he sends a form without any delay (and it end's up with a 302 redirect). I can't find any info on google what's the exact delay, carck3r says that it's 8 seconds but for me, it was 2 seconds.